# How to Bookmark selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to program the same functionality from Insert>Bookmark on Google Docs. I already used the `addBookmark(cursor)`, now I want to do it on a selected text/image. See screenshot for reference (*"congue" is the selected word*).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a bookmark at the selection using this as an example.

```
function addBookmark() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let selection = doc.getSelection();
    if( selection ) {
      let elements = selection.getRangeElements();
      let element = elements[0];
      let position = element.getStartOffset();
      position = doc.newPosition(element.getElement(),position);
      doc.addBookmark(position);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Document.getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getSelection())
- [Selection.getRangeElements()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range)
- [RangeElement.getElement()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getElement())
- [RangeElement.getStartOffset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getstartoffset)
- [Document.newPosition()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#newPosition(Element,Integer))